# Define different start points to stacked bars with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a stacked bar chart, but each bar should start at the highest point of the last bar. I have no problem on adding the start point manually for each bar, but I have no idea where to specify this in ggplot.

Here is the dataframe and the plot

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), category = rep(1:3, times=3), value = c(5, 8, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 11, 3), difference_value = c(5, 3, -4, 3, -2, 7, 5, 6, -8))

ggplot(df, aes(fill=reorder(Name, difference_value), y=difference_value, x=category)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Now, the first bar of category 1 should start at 0, but the subsequent bars should start at the end of the bar of the last category: the bar of category 2 should start in this case at  13, the stacked part of B should go down because it is negative and the values of A and C up, because they are positive.

It should be something like this:

[image: How it is vs. how it should be]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand how your `difference_values` relate to your `values`; it would seem that if the values in category 1 are 5 (A), 3 (B), and 5 (C), that means one of the `difference_values` should be negative, and the ending baseline after category 1 should be 5, not 17 (or 13 as displayed in desired output), no?

Comment: @JonSpring you are right, the bar of category 2 should start at 13 and not 17. But on the first category I do not substract anything, it starts at category 2 where: A (cat 2) - A (cat 1) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `geom_bar` or a `geom_col` always start at 0, i.e. you can't set the starting position. Instead you could use a `geom_rect` to achieve your desired result which however requires some effort to compute the start and end positions for each bar:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df <- df |>
  # Indicator for bars going down
  mutate(is_down = difference_value < 0) |>
  # Arrange dataset
  arrange(category, is_down, abs(difference_value)) |>
  # Total of bars going up
  mutate(
    total_pos = sum(difference_value[!is_down]),
    .by = category
  ) |>
  # Compute start and end of each bar
  mutate(
    ymax = cumsum(difference_value),
    ymin = lag(ymax, default = 0),
    xmin = category - .45,
    xmax = category + .45,
    .by = c(is_down, category)
  ) |>
  # Shift start and end upwards by the value of the prevoius bar
  mutate(
    across(c(ymin, ymax), ~ .x + lag(cumsum(total_pos), default = 0)),
    .by = Name
  )

ggplot(df, aes(
  fill = reorder(Name, difference_value)
)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks @stefan! I am having some problems with this. When computing the start and end of each bar, ` .by = c(is_down, category)` throws me the error: `.by` must be size 45 or 1, not 90. If I delete one of the variables in .by it works, but then the plot looks something like this (it does not show the entire bars): https://imgur.com/a/95OZB0n

Comment: Check your dplyr version. The `.by` argument was added in dplyr >= 1.1.0. From the error message I guess that your version is < 1.1.0, i.e. dplyr thinks you want to add a new column named `.by`.